# how to get data required

Tags: oracle

I have STORE_TABLE

| id | store_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | STORE A |
| 2 | STORE B |
| 3 | STORE C |

and TRANSACTION_TABLE

| id | tran_id | store | item | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 1 | ruler | 2 |
| 2 | 002 | 2 | book | 5 |
| 3 | 003 | 1 | pencil | 10 |
| 4 | 004 | 1 | tissue | 3 |
| 5 | 005 | 2 | tissue | 5 |
| 6 | 006 | 3 | tissue | 2 |
| 7 | 007 | 1 | pencil | 5 |

With oracle, what query is to find the product that sold in all store?

Comment: Please dont SPAM TAGS, if you know you want an oracle based answer then adding a MYSQL tag is a complete waste

Comment: SO is not a codewriting service. Please, post your attempt and describe what is the issue with it. In case of any errors, please post error messages and text (as text, not image). [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `PARTITION`ed  `OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT t.item
FROM   store_table s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN transaction_table t
       PARTITION BY (t.item)
       ON (s.id = t.store)
GROUP BY
       t.item
HAVING COUNT(t.store) = COUNT(s.id)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE store_table (id, store_name) AS
SELECT 1, 'STORE A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'STORE B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'STORE C' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE TRANSACTION_TABLE (id, tran_id, store, item, qty) AS
SELECT 1, '001', 1, 'ruler',   2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '002', 2, 'book',    5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '003', 1, 'pencil', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '004', 1, 'tissue',  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, '005', 2, 'tissue',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, '006', 3, 'tissue',  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, '007', 1, 'pencil',  5 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ITEM |
> | --- |
> | tissue |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=14373db1b3856743c1613abde5a5d9a4)*

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without any joins.

- count how many unique stores sell each item
- include items only when that value equals the number of stores that exist

```
SELECT
  item
FROM
  transaction_table
GROUP BY
  item
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT store) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM store_table)
```

- The `DISTINCT` is only necessary if a store can have multiple transactions for the same item

Demo, borrowed from @MT0

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=118bf2f58c6ac116c311a6947b2eff13